# In iOS14.7 beta, title of UIButton with image is truncated unexpectedly

Tags: ios, uikit

In iOS 14.7 beta 5 and RC, Title of UIButton with image is truncated unexpectedly. Please see following images.
[image]

This happens both in layout by storyboard and in layout by code.

Storyboard:
[image]

Code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setImage(.init(named: "icon_check"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])
    }
```

Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: Provide width and height for your button.

Comment: always exists on lve ios 15 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383542/uibutton-always-truncate-text-on-ios-15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior has been fixed in iOS14.7 public release version.