# UIButton always truncate text on iOS 15

Tags: uibutton, rx-swift, truncated, ios15

After update to xcode 13 / ios 15. I see, that always text is truncated on UIButton with non fix size. The text is delivered from a PushRelay (RxSwift).

[See UIButton's on a horizontal UIStackView.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puUES.png)

The Code is the following

```
  let tagButton = UIButton()
  addSubview(tagButton)
  tagButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16
  tagButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
  tagButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 16, bottom: 8, right: 16)
  tagButton.snp.makeConstraints({
    $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
  })
```

The Text is deliverd by:

```
  bag.insert(
    viewModel.outputs.titleAttrText
      .drive(tagButton.rx.attributedTitle(for: .normal))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this problem inside a UIStackView.

Switching from titleEdgeInsets to contentEdgeInsets fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is the `titleEdgeInsets` property.

Comment: I think that is the solution. If you remove the titleEdgeInsets property, the button works fine.